# Azure Automation moving blobs hashtable error

Tags: azure, automation, powershell-workflow

I am trying to create a script to move blobs from one container to another after they are processed by another automation process.  The code I am using is below.

```
workflow Move-AttendeeFiles
{
    $connectionName = Get-AutomationConnection -Name 'AzureConnection'
    $storageAccountName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'StorageAccountName'
    $storageContainerName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'toprocessContainer'
    $destContainerName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'processedContainer'

    Connect-Azure `
        -AzureConnectionName $connectionName

    inlineScript{

        Select-AzureSubscription `
            -SubscriptionName $Using:connectionName

        Set-AzureSubscription ` 
            -SubscriptionName $Using:connectionName ` 
            -CurrentStorageAccount $Using:storageAccountName 

        Get-AzureStorageBlob `
        -Container $Using:storageContainerName | Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy `
        -DestContainer $Using:destContainerName 

    }
}
```

It is throwing the below error

> Could not retrieve 'System.Collections.Hashtable' connection asset.
>   Check that you created this first in the Automation service.

I can't seem to get it running and must be staring at it to long.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Connect-Azure runbook takes as a string the connection asset name. You are passing it the connection, itself. Pass the connection name instead.

Answer (score 0):

Joe's answer got my past the Hashtable error but I had some other errors in my code.  I wanted to post the working code for everyone.

```
workflow Move-AttendeeFiles
{
    $connectionName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'azureConnectionName'
    $subId = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'azureSubscriptionId'
    $storageAccountName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'StorageAccountName'
    $storageContainerName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'toprocessContainer'
    $destContainerName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'processedContainer'

    Connect-Azure `
        -AzureConnectionName $connectionName

    inlineScript{
        Select-AzureSubscription `
            -SubscriptionName $Using:connectionName

        Set-AzureSubscription `
            -CurrentStorageAccountName $Using:storageAccountName `
            -SubscriptionId $Using:subId

    }
}
```

Note the difference in the Set-AzureSubscription code to use the -SubscriptionId instead of -SubscriptionName as that is not the proper variable.